# sending data using Bluetooth or rf transmitter with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth

I am looking at options for a project im working on. I need to send data (text strings) from a computer(s) to a computer or tablet on a forklift. I have vb.net experience but I am not sure if it is even possible to do this with vb.net. Any suggestions? Im probably not posting this in the right stack exchange site, so i apologize in advance if so.